# I am getting the Error code of "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-27-generic (5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-27-generic (5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda6
I: (UUID=09a8cb63-4799-48d8-b068-76df583caf88)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: If: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-27-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-27-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-27-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Your output suggests that you have made a typo and removed the first character of line 1 of `/etc/default/grub`. The first character of line 1 is supposed to be a comment mark (`#`) so the rest of the line is treated as a comment. Open a text editor and restore the missing character. Then try again.